# No se envia mi archivo de mi formulario a php

Tags: php, html

Hola que tal tengo un formulario y cuando hago submit y llega a la parte del servidor php no me lo detecta, pero si se envía correctamente ya que estoy comprobando por el navegador en sección de red el formdata que recibe dice: name:Prueba vacante:test ubicacion:test archivo: test.pdf
esto es mi código

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="miFormulario" action="sys/email.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre*" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduzca un nombre" />
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vacante" name="vacante" placeholder="Nombre de la vacante*" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduzca la vacante a postularse" />
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ubicacion" name="ubicacion" placeholder="Ubicación*" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Por favor introduzca la vacante a postularse" />
                                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="file-select" id="src-file1">
                                    <input type="file" id="archivo" name="archivo" aria-label="Archivo" onchange="archivoCargado()" accept=".pdf">
                                    
                                </div>
                                <p><br /></p>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-custom" type="button" onclick="enviarFrm();"  id="sendMessageButton">Enviar</button>
                                </div>

                            </form>
```

Y este es mi php el correo se envía correctamente pero no detecta el archivo lo comprobé mandando lo a imprimir e imprime como si no tuviera nada

```
$nombre = $_POST["name"];
$ubicacion = $_POST["ubicacion"];
$vacante = $_POST["vacante"];
$destinatario ="host@host.mx";
$asunto = "Formulario de bolsa de trabajo";

$cuerpoMensaje = "Nombre: $nombre\n";
$cuerpoMensaje .= "Ubicacion: $ubicacion\n";
$cuerpoMensaje .= "Vacante: $vacante\n";
$nombreArchivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
if (isset($_FILES["archivo"]) && $_FILES["archivo"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
    $archivoTemporal = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

    $contenidoArchivo = file_get_contents($archivoTemporal);

    $cuerpoMensaje .= "\n-- Adjunto --\n";
    $cuerpoMensaje .= $contenidoArchivo;
} else {
    $cuerpoMensaje .= "\n-- Sin archivo adjunto --\n";
}

$headers = "From: Bolsa\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

if (mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpoMensaje, $headers)) {
   // header("Location: ../bolsadetrabajo.html?msj=true");   
    echo "Correo enviado con éxito.--".$nombreArchivo."==".$cuerpoMensaje;
} else {
    echo "Error al enviar el correo.".$cuerpoMensaje;
}
```

Comment: Qué tienes en `enviarFrm()` ? Esa función al final es la que se ejecuta. Además que tu botón es tipo `button`, no `submit`

Comment: Ya debuggeaste tu código con la parte del archivo únicamente??

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en la declaración del formulario. Para enviar archivos debes ponerle el **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`**, [está claramente explicado en la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#enctype):

> #### `enctype`
>
> Cuando el valor del atributo `method` es `post`, este atributo es el
> tipo MIME del contenido que es usado para enviar el formulario al
> servidor. Los posibles valores son:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: El valor por defecto si un atributo no está especificado.
> - `multipart/form-data`: Usar este valor si se está usando el elemento `<input>` con el atributo `type` ajustado a "file".
> - `text/plain` (HTML5)
>
> Este valor puede ser sobreescrito por un atributo `formenctype` en un `<button>` o un elemento `<input>`.

En consecuencia, debes declarar tu formulario así, para que envíe los archivos:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="miFormulario" action="sys/email.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```